# is it possible to restrict azure vpn user to connect only company devices while using AD auth

Tags: openvpn

is it possible to restrict azure vpn user to connect only company devices while using AD auth as right now they can configure vpn to any home laptop

Comment: please elaborate, it's very hard to understand what is your current infra, and what is your wanted infra

Comment: I tried with Conditional access policy and allow only Hybrid AD users with Intune compliant devices and it worked.. thanks